# Pass an object to multiple IServiceCollection Extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I need to pass an object to several `IServiceCollection` extensions that I have created and all my extensions methods uses that object and registers their concerned dependencies. The below is how my code looks like:

Program.cs

```
var myObject = new MyObject(); //MyObject implements IMyObject
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services
       .AddMyExtension1(myObject)
       .AddMyExtension2(myObject)
       .AddMyExtension3(myObject)
       ...
       .AddMyExtensionN(myObject);

var app = builder.Build();
...
app.Run();
```

Sample Extension:

```
public static class MyExtensions{

  public static IServiceCollection AddMyExtension1(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        IMyObject myObject)
  {
     //do something
     //register some dependencies
     return services;
  }
}
```

I understand that using `BuildServiceProvider` can cause code smell/ "results in an additional copy of singleton services being created." Can anyone please recommend a better approach to use `myObject` instance in my extension methods rather than passing it as a parameter in all my method?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the actual usage of `myObject` it is hard to argue about what is the best approach. If it is required for all the custom `AddMyExtension..` methods possibly it should be just injected and resolved at runtime for corresponding registrations.

If it is not possible or just bad idea in your case you can create a new interface with implementation being basically wrapper for  `IServiceCollection` and use it for registrations. Something like this:

```cs
public interface IMyServiceCollection : IServiceCollection
{
    public IMyObject MyObject { get; }
}

class MyServiceCollection : IMyServiceCollection
{
    private readonly IServiceCollection _serviceCollection;

    public IMyObject MyObject { get; }

    public MyServiceCollection(IServiceCollection serviceCollection, IMyObject myObject)
    {
        _serviceCollection = serviceCollection;
        MyObject = myObject;
    }

    public IEnumerator<ServiceDescriptor> GetEnumerator() => _serviceCollection.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => ((IEnumerable)_serviceCollection).GetEnumerator();

    public void Add(ServiceDescriptor item) => _serviceCollection.Add(item);

    public void Clear() => _serviceCollection.Clear();

    public bool Contains(ServiceDescriptor item) => _serviceCollection.Contains(item);

    public void CopyTo(ServiceDescriptor[] array, int arrayIndex) => _serviceCollection.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);

    // the rest of IServiceCollection delegating implementation ...
}
```

Extensions:

```cs
public static class ServicesExts
{  
    public static IMyServiceCollection WithMyObject(this IServiceCollection services, IMyObject obj) => new MyServiceCollection(services, obj);
}
```

And then make all the `AddMyExtension...` methods accept and return `IMyServiceCollection` with the calls changing to:

```cs
builder.Services
    .WithMyObject(myObject)
    .AddMyExtension1()
    .AddMyExtension2()
    ...
    .AddMyExtensionN();
```

Or similar approach with value tuples:

```cs
public static class ServicesExts
{  
    public static (IServiceCollection Collection, IMyObject Object) WithMyObject(this IServiceCollection services, IMyObject obj) 
        => (services, obj);
}
```

And `AddMyExtension...` loking somewhat like:

```cs
public static (IServiceCollection Collection, object Object) AddMyExtension(this (IServiceCollection Collection, object Object) tuple)
{
     // do the registrations ...
     return tuple;
}
```

With the usage looking the same.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I use myObject to create a registry of all my dependencies. For example, I need to ensure that each of my `IRequest<>` types has an `IRequestHandler<>` implementation. 

I will try out the first approach and let you know.  Regarding the second approach, it seems like an overhead to return the object from every extension I have. So, I probably won't go ahead with that. Thanks again!

Comment: @ParthSekar first of all value tuple is not object but struct, second of all since it is used for one time setup you generally should not care.

Comment: By object I meant `myObject` in this case. Many thanks for your answer again.

Comment: _" I use myObject to create a registry of all my dependencies. For example, I need to ensure that each of my IRequest<> types has an IRequestHandler<> implementation. "_ -   based on such short description you can use `IServiceCollection` for this.